# Quarkus JAXB configuration

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, quarkus

I'm writing a Quarkus microservice and I need to upload a file and then parse it. The file upload part is all good, now I'm trying to parse file content to XML. I'm struggling with XML namespaces

I'm using this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jaxb</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and here is my resource:

```
@Path("/import")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@RequestScoped
public class FileUploadResource {
    @Inject
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller;

    @POST
    public Uni<Void> importFile(final MultipartData data) {
        try {
            Document document = (Document) this.unmarshaller.unmarshal(data.file);
            return Uni.createFrom().voidItem();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            throw new WebApplicationException(500);
        }
    }
}
```

Models:

```
@RegisterForReflection
public class MultipartData {
    @RestForm
    public InputStream file;
}
```

```
@XmlRootElement(namespace = "some-namespace", name="Document")
public class Document {
    @XmlElement(namespace = "some-namespace")
    public Element element;
}
```

I'm uploading files with this root element: `<Document xmlns="some-namespace" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">` but namespaces can potentially change.

I experienced that Element is null if the namespace is not specified. Is it possible (and good practice) to unmarshall xml files regardless of the namespace?

I tried this way: https://quarkus.io/guides/resteasy-reactive#customize-the-jaxb-configuration but I don't find the correct customization

Comment: The whole point with namespaces is that ns1:Whatever should be different from ns2:Whatever if ns1 and ns2 are different namespaces. If you are using namespaces, ignoring them is certainly not good practice (my opinion). Given a choice I would reject bad data as early as possible. If the caller got the namespace wrong, there may be other and more subtle errors too.

Comment: Ok thanks, I understand. Do I have to annotate every element/attribute or is there a way to propagate the namespace annotation?

Comment: I don't think you need to annotate everything, but my XML skills are a bit rusty. I'll leave that answer to someone else.